# DirectUs 9 how to filter data?

Tags: directus

I am trying to filter my blog articles by categories but I failed to achieve my target.

I tried

[https://irresistiblemt.in/jsfnk43b5/items/Articles?filter=[Post_Category][Articles_id][Categories_id][_eq]=1](https://stackoverflow.com)

---

Here is my temporary blog url : [https://irresistiblemt.in/jsfnk43b5/items/Articles?fields=*.*.*](https://stackoverflow.com)

I want to fetch all the posts from a particular category.
I am using Nuxt 3 and I can get blog posts by DirectUs SDK.
Here is my code :

```
<script setup>
const { $directus } = useNuxtApp();
const { data: posts } = await useAsyncData("Articles", () => {
   return $directus.items("Articles").readByQuery({
       fields: [
           'id',
           'slug',
           'Featured_Image.id',
           'date_created',
           'Post_Category.Categories_id.Title',
           'Title',
           'Description',
       ],
       sort: ['-date_created'],
});
});
</script>
```

And in template :

```
<div class="bg-primary-50 border-b border-solid flex flex-col mb-5 shadow" v-for="post in posts.data">
                          <div>
                              <img :src="`${$directus.url}/assets/${post.Featured_Image.id}?fit=cover&width=700&height=300&quality=50`"  class="hover:mix-blend-luminosity w-screen h-full" >
                          </div>
                          <div class="pl-5 pt-5">
                              <button class="font-medium mr-2 pb-5 text-links-500 text-sm uppercase">{{ post.Post_Category[0].Categories_id.Title }}</button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="pb-5 px-5">
                              <h1 class="font-bold text-3xl text-dark2-500">{{ post.Title }}</h1>
                          </div>
                          <div class="pb-5 pl-5">
                              <p class="font-medium text-dark2-500 text-sm">Published on {{ post.date_created }}</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="pb-5 px-5">
                              <p class="font-medium text-dark2-500">{{ post.Description }}</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="font-medium hover:text-links-500 p-5 text-bgdark-900 uppercase" data-pg-name="Read More">
                              <NuxtLink :to="`blog/${post.id}`" class="uppercase text-gray-800 hover:text-black">Continue Reading </NuxtLink>
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

How can I get posts for a particular category? (Category Archives)